# Apply css with focus on its own class

Tags: html, css

I want to apply the css with focus selector on its own class. I just wan't to hide  the class of focus it self. Here is my code snippet.

```css
body {
  display: block;
}
.span3:focus ~ .alert {
  display: none;
}
.span2:focus ~ .alert {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
 <span class="span3" tabindex="0">Hide Me</span>
<span class="span2" tabindex="0">Show Me</span>
<p class="alert">Some alarming information here</p>
```

Comment: can't understand what you are saying

Comment: what do u mean to say man?

Comment: Yup, seems to be working fine for me too

Comment: code snipped works fine for me

Comment: It's not working fine. If you click on Hide Me then it will be hide only if you don't click on any section of the webpage. If you click then it will reset and will be visible. @Pete

Comment: Just run the above Code Snippet and click on Hide me ...
And then click any where... it will show again....

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the answer to your question, you should use javascript. A little script, and delete some lines of css.

https://jsfiddle.net/prsebqg3/

---

html file

```
<span id="span3" tabindex="0">Hide Me</span>
<span id="span2" tabindex="0">Show Me</span>
<p id="alert" >Some alarming information here</p>

<script>
    document.getElementById("span3").onclick = function() {functionHide()};

    function functionHide() {
        document.getElementById("span2").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("span3").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("alert").style.display = "none";    
    }

    document.getElementById("span2").onclick = function() {functionShow()};

    function functionShow() {
        document.getElementById("span2").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("span3").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("alert").style.display = "block";    
    }
</scrip>
```

css file

```
#span2{
  display:none;
}
```

Comment: Actually i'm trying to do this work in a email template. So that i cannot use jquery Or java script for some reason. I only wan't to do this task with css only.